# Android Studio "R.array" Error:(36, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable array

Tags: android, arrays

Error highlights the text "array" red. How do I fix it?

```
public class Signup extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView y;
    String[] z;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        y = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.cntry);
        z = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, z);
```

Comment: You have answer here [create Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774668/resource-arrays)

Comment: `R.x.foo` is "automatically" generated by the resource file/manifest. If the compiler is throwing an error about `x.foo`, then the chances are `x.foo` does not correspond to a defined resource.

Answer (score 0):

You use a TypedArray in arrays.xml file within your res/values folder that looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="country">
        <item>@drawable/pakistan</item>
        <item>@drawable/india</item>
        <item>@drawable/USA</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```